# store and send data to service after calling WriteAsync in realm

Tags: xamarin, realm

i am trying to create a customer and save it in a `Realm` database using `WriteAsync` method. Once the customer get stored i am sending this data to server from add customer screen only and showing loader accordingly.

here is the code ,

```
 var newCustomer = new Customer
    {

        organizationName = etOrganization.Text
        firstName = etFirstName.Text,
        lastName = etLastName.Text,
    };
        await _realmInstance.WriteAsync(temp =>
        {
            _realmInstance.Add(newCustomer , true);

        });

        createUpdateCustomer(newCustomer);
```

but i am getting error i.e. `Realm Already Closed` , i do under stand `WriteAsync` will close the realm once it inserts the data. so in this case what would be the best approach to store and send data to service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing `newCustomer` to another function *after* it becomes Realm managed, you will either have to retrieve a new instance of the object in the current thread after adding/updating it via your `WriteAsync` call, or use `Write` instead, i.e.

```
_realmInstance.Write(() =>
{
    _realmInstance.Add(newCustomer , true);
});
createUpdateCustomer(newCustomer);
```

Or:

```
await _realmInstance.WriteAsync(temp =>
{
    temp.Add(newCustomer , true);
});
// use Find if your RealmObject has a primary key...
var customer = _realmInstance.Find<Customer>(.......);
// otherwise use Where with First...
var customer = _realmInstance.All<Customer>().Where(_ => _.firstName == ~~~ & _.lastName == ~~~).First();
createUpdateCustomer(customer);
```

Using `WriteAsync` in this case is not worth the overhead, just use `Write`.

Comment: i tried `temp` and now i am getting `Realms.Exceptions.RealmClosedException: This object belongs to a closed realm.` error , i check _realmInstance is not getting closed anywhere

Comment: @Hunt *Before* you call `WriteAsync`, check your Realm instance ( `_realmInstance`) via `IsClosed`. Is it true?

Comment: Nope its false `Debug.WriteLine("Realm Status " + _realmInstance.IsClosed);`  i checked it

Comment: i am calling  createUpdateCustomer(newCustomer); and when i debug the newCustomer object it hat the `Realms.Exceptions.RealmClosedException:`

Comment: WriteAsync will going to close the realm hence newCustomer object might be throwing `this object belongs to a closed realm` if i use `realm.Write` then its working fine

Comment: @Hunt Now knowing that the issue is within `createUpdateCustomer`, I updated my answer...

Comment: Another approach would be to use the newly introduced [ThreadSafeReference](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) API: in the `WriteAsync` block, you can do `reference = ThreadSafeReference.Create(newCustomer)` and later - `var customer = _realmInstance.Resolve(reference)`.